# Can we bring DataTable to Listview

Tags: vb.net

Im using vb.net 2003 and working desktop application.I want to bring DataTable data to list view where their columns are already added.We want to jus point the index to arrange data.Please anyone help on this.

Comment: Do not ask to write your code for you : Instead try out something and if you face any error/difficulty then ask a question around it with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Items` and `SubItems` collection of ListView. Take a look at MSDN [article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)